# SQL to find name of customer who placed an order with 100 or less

Tags: sql

Table `Orders`:

```
(order_num: 002; 010; 003), 
(order_amt: 50.6; 99.66; 101), 
(customer_id: 06; 02; 03)
```

Table `Customer`:

```
(customer_id: 02; 06; 03), 
(customer_name: James; Mike; Dan), 
(city: Miami; London; Berlin)
```

That is all the info that is given

```
SELECT customer_name
FROM Customer
WHERE customer_id IN (
  SELECT customer_id
  FROM Orders
  WHERE order_amt < 100
);
```

===========================

```
SELECT c.customer_name
  FROM Customer c
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM Orders o
               WHERE c.customer_id = o.customer_id
                 AND o.order_amt < 100);
```

===========================

```
SELECT c.customer_name
  FROM Orders o
  JOIN Customer c
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.customer_name      
HAVING SUM(o.order_amt) < 100;
```

===========================

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.customer_name
  FROM Orders o
  JOIN Customer c
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
 WHERE o.order_amt < 100;
```

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you're using. are you using MySQL or SQL Server? I have removed the conflicting tags. What was wrong with your attempt? If you are using SQL Server, then `==` will result in an error.

Comment: I think you mean **total order for each** individual, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need an outer join, since every order's `customer_id` should already exist within the customer table logically, but inner join with matching `customer_id` column containing a `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT c.customer_name
  FROM Orders o
  JOIN Customer c
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.customer_name      
HAVING SUM(o.order_amt) < 100
```

If you look for each individual order with order_amt less than 100 **regardless** of
**total order** for **each customer**, then consider using :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.customer_name
  FROM Orders o
  JOIN Customer c
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
 WHERE o.order_amt < 100
```

without `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the operator `IN` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT customer_name
FROM Customer
WHERE customer_id IN (
  SELECT customer_id
  FROM Orders
  WHERE order_amt < 100
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For better performance, You might want to try EXISTS clause -

```
SELECT c.customer_name
  FROM Customer c
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM Orders o
               WHERE c.customer_id = o.customer_id
                 AND o.order_amt < 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Need not use GROUP BY, I think EXISTS or LEFT SEMI JOIN is ok.

```
WITH 
Customer(customer_id, customer_name, city) AS (
VALUES ('01', 'Mike', 'New York'), ('05', 'Zusi', 'California'), ('02', 'Green', 'London')),
Orders(order_num, order_amt, customer_id) AS (
VALUES ('001', 50.5, '05'),('009', 99.65, '01'),('002', 100, '02'))

SELECT A.customer_name
FROM Customer AS A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM Orders AS B
  WHERE A.customer_id = B.customer_id
    AND B.order_amt < 100
)
```